# Meteor doesn't install fibers in bundle

Tags: meteor

I created a bundle and try install as wrote in readme

```
> node ./build.js


module.js:340
    throw err;
      ^
Error: Cannot find module '/root/bundle/programs/server/node_modules/fibers/build.js'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
at startup (node.js:119:16)
at node.js:906:3

npm ERR! fibers@1.0.1 install: `node ./build.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 8
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the fibers@1.0.1 install script.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the fibers package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node ./build.js
```

npm install -g fiders works as well

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the same problem, but starting with [0.9.0](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/History.md#v090) you have to install fibers after unpacking the build. From the readme:

> To prepare a bundle created with meteor bundle for execution on a server, you now run npm install with no arguments instead of having to specify a few specific npm modules and their versions explicitly. See the README in the generated bundle for more details.

I do something like this in my deployment script:

```
meteor bundle /path/to/target/bundle.tgz
cd /path/to/target/
rm -rf bundle
tar xzf bundle.tgz
cd bundle/programs/server && npm install
```

Comment: What version of node are you running on your server?

Comment: last avaliable on the official site v0.10.32

Comment: I always run whatever the latest tested version is in the [changelog](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/History.md). Currently that's `0.10.29`. I have no idea if that would cause your problem but it may be worth a shot if you are still stuck.